# setting CellStyle() for each cell taking forever in case of large data(Thousands of rows & columns)

Tags: java, apache-poi

As part of our project, we have to build an excel report, which will have thousands of rows and columns. in this many of the cells in each row will have different cell styling like, text in green color, text in red color, different background fills etc..

Could some one please suggest a better way to handle this scenario?

Please let me know if any concerns.

I have tried applying CellStyle to each cell in a row. using ..getCell().setCellStyle(). but this operation is consuming lot of time when many rows and many columns exists. As a result, for huge data the excel report itself is not getting downloaded forever. I have also tried applying rowStyle first and later applying individual cell style wherever needed. But applying rowStyle is behaving bit different. applying rowStyle is not impacting Existing cellstyles in excel template and the one's where cell wont be present and i create the cell from java code, which is an issue for us. if RowStyle is applied to all the cells present in that row irrespective of cell already has cellstyle or cell is not present, then we should be good.

I cannot post the code as per company policies. I regret for that.

I am expecting to apply required style to each cell and the execution should not take much time.

Thanks,
Sagar.

Comment: how can we know what you are trying and what problem you are facing? from question it is not very clear. Not actual code but you can paste simulation so other person will understand

Comment: @Sagar create pre defend cell styles firstlly, then based on the value of cell set the related cell style

Comment: @Rathnayake,

Caching the required cell styles and applying it wherever needed worked for me. thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to be carefull when it comes to cellStyles. Excel only allows a sepcific amount of cellStyles in a workbook (Excel 2003 ~ 4000 | Excel 2007 and later ~64000 as noted [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/213904/you-receive-a-too-many-different-cell-formats-error-message-in-excel)).

Instead of creating a new `cellStyle` for each cell, you should define your cellStyles, cache them and assign them to the cell when needed.

Instead of doing this:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) 
   {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        Font font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        style.setFont(font);
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
    }
```

You should do something like this:

```
   CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
   Font font = workbook.createFont();
   font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
   style.setFont(font);
   for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) 
   {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
    }
```

You can read more about this [here](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#WorkingWithFonts).

Comment: Caching the required cell styles and applying it wherever needed worked for me. thanks a lot:)